# Using libjpeg with a 8-bit grayscale source image, can it be done?

Tags: libjpeg

I am using the libjpeg to create jpegs

http://www.ijg.org/

However it works only if I pass 3-component rba images to it. If I try to pass a 1 component grayscale image it does not work. Specifically, this worked:

```
#define COLOR_COMPONENTS    (3)
#define COLOR_SPACE         (JCS_RGB)
JSAMPLE image_buffer[WIDTH*HEIGHT *3] = 
{
0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,    0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
};

...
// inside libjpeg I set the values
cinfo.image_width = image_width;    /* image width and height, in pixels */
cinfo.image_height = image_height;
cinfo.input_components = COLOR_COMPONENTS;      /* # of color components per pixel */
cinfo.in_color_space = COLOR_SPACE;     /* colorspace of input image */
/* Now use the library's routine to set default compression parameters.
* (You must set at least cinfo.in_color_space before calling this,
* since the defaults depend on the source color space.)
*/
jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
```

However this does not work:

```
#define COLOR_COMPONENTS    (1)
#define COLOR_SPACE         (JCS_GRAYSCALE)
JSAMPLE image_buffer[WIDTH*HEIGHT * 1] =
{
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
};
```

Can I use libjpeg to encode 8-bit images? What would be the correct settings for the code below?

```
cinfo.input_components = ???
cinfo.in_color_space = ???
```

the code needs to to run on a low clock CPU. Therefore, I don't have cycles to spare to converting from gray scale image into and RGB.

thank you!

Comment: What is RBA please? You use it twice.

Comment: I meant RGB, I did not use it twice. Three components per pixel on the first array. One byte for each color: red, blue and green

Comment: Can you provide a **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example** which can be compiled and run please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: nevermind, I found my bug. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found out what the problem is. The row stride needs to match the color space.

The original source had:

```
row_stride = image_width * 3;   /* JSAMPLEs per row in image_buffer */
```

I just changed the row_stride to 1, since it's is a gray scale using 1 byte per pixel

```
row_stride = image_width * 1;   /* JSAMPLEs per row in image_buffer */
```

thanks for reading in all cases.